# Unable to clone repo in windows

Tags: git, bitbucket, emacs24

I am attempting to clone a repo into a windows folder and am getting the following output:

```
git clone https://terry_marange@bitbucket.org/terry_marange/emacs_config.git
Cloning into 'emacs_config'...
error: unable to create file lessons /code_snipptes_emacs: No such file or directory
error: unable to create file lessons /code_snipptes_emacs~: No such file or directory
error: unable to create file lessons /notes: No such file or directory
error: unable to create file lessons /notes~: No such file or directory
Checking out files: 100% (1406/1406), done.
fatal: unable to checkout working tree
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry the checkout with 'git checkout -f HEAD'
```

- attempted enabling core.longpaths and it didnt work.
- attempted to clone the repo closer to the root ie. c:\ and it didnt work.

Comment: It seems there are white spaces in your path. Perhaps, they are the cause (or another path naming issue)?

Comment: There are no whitespaces in the location where I'm trying to clone. The path I'm trying to clone to is c:\

Comment: Strangely cloning the repo works fine in linux

Comment: Just search `fatal: unable to checkout working tree`: In many cases it is about what is accepted as path...